# ModelState.isValid is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There is a lead:

```cs
public class Leads
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Who contains one or more vehicles:

```cs
public class Vehicles
{
    public Vehicles()
    {
        Hash = Helpers.CreateGuid();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Leads Lead { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Everytime I try to update the vehicle, modelState is not valid.
The problem is on the Lead and it says that it should be required. And it´s true.

When I receive on the post:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Lead,Hash,Brand,Model")] Vehicles vehicles)
{
    if (id != vehicles.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid) ...
```

And ModelState.IsValid is ALWAYS false...
And I tried to add this before...

```cs
var lead = _context.Leads.Find(int.Parse( Request.Form["Lead"].ToString()));
vehicles.Lead = lead;
```

But same problem... Lead is empty, and the model requires that It has a value...

What´s wrong?

Comment: how are you sending data to Edit action?

Comment: A bit strange. In the Vehicles model you have Lead property of type Leads.

But here:
var lead = _context.Leads.Find(int.Parse( Request.Form["Lead"].ToString()));

You expect it to be a number in the form data. Check what data do you pass to your action method. And to be honest - I would rather use another model for accepting edit data, instead of using Bind attribute.

Comment: whati is the value of Request.Form["Lead"].ToString()?

Comment: @Nonik by post.. it´s just a form..

Comment: @VolodymyrPuzdriak you refer to use some kind of DTO (ex viewModel) instead of same model as I use in the database? the lead value is a number:             <input type="hidden" value="1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Lead field is required." id="Lead" name="Lead" />

Comment: @user2809176 this is the form:             <input type="hidden" value="1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Lead field is required." id="Lead" name="Lead" />

Comment: @Ariel, yes I mean viewmodel. Using your database model is not a good practise. Your database model instance is the object presentation of your record in database with related records to it. In many cases on your views you do not need to fill every related object. If you are editing the car - the id of the lead will be sufficient. Then on the backend, you can check if this lead exists in database. If does - then you can map the viewmodel on your database model and update your car.

Comment: @VolodymyrPuzdriak ok, i will change to viewModels.. And when i ask again for the modelState.isValid() the modelstate is related to the model to update on database or on the ViewModel?

Comment: @Ariel - you have to add validation attributes to the view model. Then ModelState.IsValid will check the state on the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

> But same problem... Lead is empty, and the model requires that It has a value...

Yes, this is the reason. The `Name` property in Lead class is required, it must have a value.

You may add inputs for properties in `Lead` in the view like this:

```
<input asp-for="Lead.Id" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="Lead.Name" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Why Lead.Name is required? If i just need to map the id of the lead?